# Solve a Linear Equation

Tags: linear-algebra

Please help to solve this problem.what is the answer of this equation. Is it any famous problem?

If $a,b,c\in\mathbb{C}$ such that
$$a+b\neq0,\quad b+c\neq0,\quad a+c\neq0\\a+b+c=-23,\quad ab+ac+bc=-324$$
Then what is the value of $x$ in the following equation?
$$\frac{x^2+2b^2+c^2}{a+b}+\frac{x^2+2c^2+a^2}{b+c}+\frac{x^2+2a^2+b^2}{a+c}=0$$

Comment: tags like differential equation,  complex numbers, Diophantine equation are not applicable

Comment: @labbhattacharjee, I removed all but complex numbers, but if you can come up with a better tag, go ahead.

Comment: @Mash, I have rectified the title & the tag.

Comment: @yanbo, you have changed $x$ to $x^2,$ while editing if I'm not mistaken

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I am terribly sorry if I did, but I thought I saw $x^2$. Could OP please check?

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

$$\frac{x+2b^2+c^2}{a+b}=\frac{x+a^2+b^2+c^2+b^2-a^2}{a+b}=\frac{x+a^2+b^2+c^2}{a+b}+b-a$$

and  $$a^2+b^2+c^2=(a+b+c)^2-2(ab+bc+ca)$$